# File location issue even if the file is available

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

I have a following lines of code in python. I have to copy from table and pass it to the given file location. I do have a file named distance.txt but it errors file not found as file is already available in that location.

Can anybody tell what mistake I did.

```
cur.execute(("""COPY (select source, target, sum(cost)/1000 as cost from dm where source != 88888888 and target != 88888888 group by source, target order by source) TO '%s\\distance.txt'""") % (os.getcwd()))
con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'distance.txt')

cur.execute("""COPY (select source, target, sum(cost)/1000 as cost from dm where source != 88888888 and target != 88888888 group by source, target order by source) TO '%s'""" % (filepath))
con.commit()
```

Comment: your parentheses are unbalanced I think

Answer (score 0):

From the [DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) documentation:

> ```
> # Never do this -- insecure!
> symbol = 'RHAT'
> c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)
>
> # Do this instead
> t = ('RHAT',)
> c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
> print(c.fetchone())
> ```

---

Applying that rule to your problem, leads us here:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'distance.txt')

cur.execute("COPY (Select * FROM SomeTable) TO ?", (filepath, ))
con.commit()
```